# perl Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified

Tags: perl, http, ssl, certificate, lwp

I am having trouble with a perl screenscraper to an HTTPS site. 
In debugging, I ran the following:

```
print $res->headers_as_string;
```

and in the output, I have the following line:

```
Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified
```

Is there a way I can auto-accept this certificate, or is that not the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use LWP::UserAgent; 
use Crypt::SSLeay::CTX; 
use Crypt::SSLeay::Conn; 
use Crypt::SSLeay::X509; 
use LWP::Simple qw(get);

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://vzw-cat.sun4.lightsurf.net/vzwcampaignadmin/');
my $res = $ua->request($req);

print $res->headers_as_string;
```

output:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 19:28:08 GMT
Pragma: No-cache
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST
Client-Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 19:28:09 GMT
Client-Peer: 64.152.68.114:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /O=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3/OU=www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Boston/O=verizon wireless/OU=TERMS OF USE AT WWW.VERISIGN.COM/RPA (C)00/CN=PSMSADMIN.VZW.COM
Client-SSL-Cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Link: <css/vtext_style.css>; rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DE6C99EA2F3DD1D4DF31456B94F16C90.vz3; Path=/vzwcampaignadmin; Secure
Title: Verizon Wireless - Campaign Administrator
```

UPDATE:
I added

```
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_FILE}   = 'certs/PSMSADMIN.VZW.COM';
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_DIR}    = 'certs/';
```

as suggested below.  I also turned on debugging:

```
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;
```

Here is my output:

```
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL3 alert write:fatal:bad certificate
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 read server certificate B
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2 read server hello B
content: 500 SSL negotiation failed: error:1407E086:SSL routines:SSL2_SET_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I try to ignore the failure, but the problem is that that is the only thing on the page now, so no login form or anything.

Comment: Can you post your output? I get a 200 OK and what I assume is the correct document. Yes, the header has a warning, but can you clarify how this detrimentally affects the behavior of your program?

Comment: the problem is that I can't get logged in.  After submitting the credentials, it goes back to the login page.

Comment: You might want to kick up the HTTP debug level a bit. I'm not sure this is an SSL problem. Can you output the status code and body too? I obviously don't have the credentials to test this :-D

Comment: Well, I should say that I do get logged in, but only after running the above script separately from my screen scraper.  It's strange, it works for a couple days and then fails to login again.  I have been trying to figure out what about this script is causing it to work.  

Another interesting tidbit, why does it look like the cert is expired?  Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST

Comment: Ok, I think I just figured out why that was happening.  I had use IO::Socket::SSL; in another pm the main script calls and I think that was hijacking all SSL communication.  After removing this, my I get the desired result each time.  I think I have solved this, but I have to wait a couple days to be sure.  :)

Comment: only part way solved... i added an update to the original post

Answer (score 4):

As near as I can tell, this is only a warning. The certificate on that site does not match the domain, so perl is (rightfully) complaining about it. If you actually turn on peer certificate verification like so:

```
# CA cert peer verification
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_FILE}   = 'certs/ca-bundle.crt';
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_DIR}    = 'certs/';
```

You'll get this as your output:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 19:32:51 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response
500 SSL negotiation failed: error:1407E086:SSL
      routines:SSL2_SET_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 19:32:51 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response
```

There is a method named [`get_peer_verify`](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Crypt-SSLeay-0.57/lib/Net/SSL.pm#get_peer_verify) in `Net::SSL` (which `Crypt::SSLeay` provides) which returns whether or not peer verification is desired. I believe it was added [in 2001](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Crypt-SSLeay/Changes.html) or so in order to enable this message to be hidden. [This patch](http://www.mail-archive.com/libwww@perl.org/msg03129.html) from 2002 claims to turn off the warning when peer verification is not desired, but I don't think it was ever applied.

So in short, you can probably ignore the warning unless you mean to be doing verification, in which case I'd say add the root cert to your `CA_DIR` and `CA_FILE`. But since the cert's domain doesn't match the domain of the server, I'm not even sure that this will help.